# MySQL Triggers - AFTER UPDATE on table condition DELETE A ROW IF condition

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, database-trigger

So basically, I have a `posts` table having columns `p_id` and `pid`.

```
p_id | pid
-----------
1    | 2
2    | 8
.      .
.      .
.      .
```

They are controlled by frontend and server is connected to this database.

Now, I am updating value of `pid` frequently.

What I want, is to delete the row which AFTER UPDATING `pid` of the table `if p_id-pid < -10`

So, I am writing (after changing delimiter to `//` from `;`),

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleteiften AFTER UPDATE on posts 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    begin 
        IF NEW.p_id-NEW.pid<-10 THEN delete from posts where p_id-pid<-10; 
        END IF; 
    end; 
//
```

Now, when I have `p_id` as 20 and and update `pid` to 31,

```
update posts set pid=31 where p_id=20;
```

I have following error,

```
ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'posts' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

I understand this error that it won't be able to update as the condition is there,

BUT I don't want error. I just want to DELETE the row automatically if the `pid` UPDATE meets the trigger condition. I am stuck here.

I hope you understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: You can't do that in a trigger. You would need to write a stored procedure that `update`s and `delete`s, and call it from your application.

Comment: instead of deleting start an event and delete it some seconds later, It is nitpossilbe the change a table, that caused  the trigger

Comment: Thanks for the response! But is there no way to do what I want in the database itself ? @GMB

Comment: @SarvagnaShukla: a stored procedure is a database object (that's like a batch of sql statements). But instead of adding overhead to your busy live application, why not periodically purge old entries in another process?